# How Do I Read Triggers

Tags: sql

Please what does the trigger below mean

```
 FOR EACH ROW 
    DELETE FROM PageRevisions WHERE name = OLD.name;   
    INSERT INTO deletelog 
    VALUES (old.name, NOW());
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Triggers are highly vendor specific. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

FOR EACH ROW

FOR EACH STATEMENT

This specifies whether the trigger procedure should be fired once for every row affected by the trigger event, or just once per SQL statement. 
If neither is specified, FOR EACH STATEMENT is the default.